# I have a problem with the arrayPizzas, it never enters the first if, what is the problem? I want to put a count ++ for duplicate list items

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
this.arrayPizzas = [
    0: {
        name: "4 Stagioni",
        price: 13,
        ingredients: "250 g of pizza dough, 150 g of tomato sauce, 30 g …ck and green olives, 30 g of champignon mushrooms",
        image: "../assets/img/pizza-4stag.png"
    },
    1: {
        name: "Margherita",
        price: 10,
        ingredients: "Manitoba flour 200 g, Water 300 ml, Salt up to 10 g, Extra virgin olive oil 35 g, Tomato pulp 500 g",
        image: "../assets/img/pizza-margherita.png"
    },
    2: {
        name: "Margherita",
        price: 10,
        ingredients: "Manitoba flour 200 g, Water 300 ml, Salt up to 10 g, Extra virgin olive oil 35 g, Tomato pulp 500 g",
        image: "../assets/img/pizza-margherita.png"
    },
    3: {
        name: "Margherita",
        price: 10,
        ingredients: "Manitoba flour 200 g, Water 300 ml, Salt up to 10 g, Extra virgin olive oil 35 g, Tomato pulp 500 g",
        image: "../assets/img/pizza-margherita.png"
    },
    4: {
        name: "Vegetarian",
        price: 13.5,
        ingredients: "400 g of pizza dough, 300 g of tomato sauce, 1 eggplant, 2 peppers, 1 courgette",
        image: "../assets/img/pizza-vegetariana.png"
    },
    5: {
        name: "Vegetarian",
        price: 13.5,
        ingredients: "400 g of pizza dough, 300 g of}];

    this.arrayPizzas = this.local.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1);
    this.arrayPizzas.forEach(element => {
            const count = 0;
            if (this.newArray.includes(element.name)) {
                console.log('include');
                this.newArray[element].counter = element.counter + 1;
            } else if (!this.newArray.includes(element.name)) {
                console.log('else');
                const a: Cart = {
                    name: element.name,
                    counter: count,
                    price: element.price
                };
                this.newArray.push(a);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What's newArray? Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: why are you sorting and then finding duplicates? sorting is the final thing you want to do

Comment: I have so many questions. The main one is: in simple terms, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: people should not be closing questions wich don't have a valid reason to be closed!

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you and count the occurrence of the pizza names

```js
arrayPizzas = [{
    name: "Margherita",
    price: 10,
    ingredients: "Manitoba flour 200 g, Water 300 ml, Salt up to 10 g, Extra virgin olive oil 35 g, Tomato pulp 500 g",
    image: "../assets/img/pizza-margherita.png"
  },

  {
    name: "Vegetarian",
    price: 13.5,
    ingredients: "400 g of pizza dough, 300 g of tomato sauce, 1 eggplant, 2 peppers, 1 courgette",
    image: "../assets/img/pizza-vegetariana.png"
  },

  {
    name: "Vegetarian",
    price: 13.5,
    ingredients: "400 g of pizza dough, 300 g of"
  }
]
newArray = [];


this.arrayPizzas.forEach((element) => {
  const index = this.newArray.findIndex(x => x.name === element.name)
  if (index > -1) {
    this.newArray[index].counter += 1
  } else {
    const a = {
      name: element.name,
      counter: 1,
      price: element.price
    };
    this.newArray.push(a);
  }

});

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overwriting your array's contents with

```
this.arrayPizzas = this.local.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1);
```

try calling the sort function on it as probably intended

```
this.arrayPizzas.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array contains objects all of which have different reference. It will never be equal so it doesn't return a non zero value when you find it using include.

So even when you have seen the same object by value it is different by reference.

```js
let test = [{a:1},{a:1}]

console.log(test[0]===test[1])
```